# Use QMatrix4x4 with OpenGL functions

Tags: qt, opengl

Is there an easy way to use `QMatrix4x4` with OpenGL functions, specifically `glMultMatrixf`?

If I understand this right, I'd have to transpose the matrix, and be sure to convert `qreal` (which can be either `float` or `double` depending on the underlying system) to `GLfloat`. 
Isn't there a function which does this for me?

I also have the same problem with `QVector3D`, which again I need as `GLfloat` array in the function `glVertex3fv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I want to mention that `QMatrix4x4` has built-in operators for matrix multiplication (with a second matrix, a vector or a scalar). However, your question still needs an answer, as you want to pass a matrix to OpenGL sooner or later.

`QMatrix4x4` uses `qreals` for internal representation. While the class is intended to be used with OpenGL directly (using `constData()` as suggested by Bart in his answer), you can make sure you pass it to the corresponding OpenGL function depending on the type, if you want to keep platform compatibility (on embedded devices, `qreal` is `float`!):

```
// these are defined in the OpenGL headers:
void glMultMatrixf(const GLfloat *m);
void glMultMatrixd(const GLdouble *m);

// add overloaded functions which call the underlying OpenGL function
inline void glMultMatrix(const GLfloat  *m) { glMultMatrixf(m); }
inline void glMultMatrix(const GLdouble *m) { glMultMatrixd(m); }

// add an overload for QMatrix4x4 for convenience
inline void glMultMatrix(const QMatrix4x4 &m) { glMultMatrix(m.constData()); }
```

You can also use this mechanism for vectors, here the `glVertex*` family, where it makes even more sense because of the number of components the "raw pointer" overloads need to consider, but the object oriented overloads can do automatically for you:

```
inline void glVertex2v(const GLfloat  *v) { glVertex2fv(v); }
inline void glVertex2v(const GLdouble *v) { glVertex2dv(v); }
inline void glVertex3v(const GLfloat  *v) { glVertex3fv(v); }
inline void glVertex3v(const GLdouble *v) { glVertex3dv(v); }
inline void glVertex4v(const GLfloat  *v) { glVertex4fv(v); }
inline void glVertex4v(const GLdouble *v) { glVertex4dv(v); }

// Note that QVectorND use floats, but we check this during compile time...
Q_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(QVector2D) == 2*sizeof(float));
Q_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(QVector3D) == 3*sizeof(float));
Q_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(QVector4D) == 4*sizeof(float));
inline void glVertex(const QVector2D &v) { glVertex2v(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&v)); }
inline void glVertex(const QVector3D &v) { glVertex3v(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&v)); }
inline void glVertex(const QVector4D &v) { glVertex4v(reinterpret_cast<const float*>(&v)); }

// Even for QPointF we can do it!
Q_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(QPointF) == 2*sizeof(qreal));
inline void glVertex(const QPointF &v) { glVertex4v(reinterpret_cast<const qreal*>(&v)); }
```

So your code keeps valid if the following changes are made:

- Qt changes the representation of `QVector*` / `QMatrix` to use floats / doubles respectively,
- Your code changes the number of components of vectors

... while especially the second isn't the case when using raw OpenGL commands like `glVertex3f`.

The `Q_STATIC_ASSERT`ions in the code above are only defined since Qt 5.0. If you are using Qt4 (or code with Qt4 compatibility), add this in some global header file / before your definitions: http://ideone.com/VDPUSg [source: Qt5 / qglobal.h]

Comment: thank you, exactly what I needed (although I would have preferred the answer, that Qt provides exactly this)

Comment: @Misch Well, there is this [QGLFunctions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglfunctions.html) mixin, so you silently use Qt's OpenGL function wrappers if you inherit from this mixin. However, they haven't been that clever to introduce overloads. Maybe there is a good reason -- but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2):

`qreal` is defined to be a double on all platforms, except for ARM architectures. So most likely for you they are doubles.

That said, yes, you can use your QMatrix4x4 perfectly fine with OpenGL, using the [`constData()`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmatrix4x4.html#constData) method. Of course with a double type you would either have to use `glMultMatrixd`, or create a float matrix out of it. Which might not be what you want to do. There are various examples by Qt which use the matrix type in their OpenGL demos.

I personally never use Qt's matrix and vector types for my OpenGL code though (even though I extensively use Qt), but rather go for a library like Eigen, GLM, or something else suitable.

Comment: Are you sure that `constData()` is giving me what I want? Don't I have to transpose the matrix to use it witch OpenGL?

Comment: @Misch As per the code documentation, the data is specifically laid out so as to be optimal for passing to OpenGL functions. So no, you won't need to worry about that.

Comment: I can't find this for sure in the Qt documentation, but I thought that `constData` returns its data in a row-major way. (The only thing I found was this: "The contents of the array values is assumed to be in row-major order." in the constructor of `QGenericMatrix`). However OpenGL uses column-major matrixes

Comment: @Misch Nah, it doesn't really. OpenGL wants a contiguous array of data with with translation values as the 13th to 15th value. Which is exactly what constData will give you. Row-major vs colum-major is this big OpenGL confusion which is not really needed. See the OpenGL FAQ on this issue: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm Do you face any particular problems?

Comment: @Misch The Qt documentation is indeed confusing in this regard. But internally the data has an OpenGL compliant layout. There have been bug reports specifically about the documentation, so one can only hope this gets clarified at some point.